# what is there "integer" in PDO predefined constants?

Tags: php, pdo, constants

found from [predefined constants](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php).
what is the (integer) means? why all (integer)?

> ```
> PDO::PARAM_BOOL (integer)
> Represents a boolean data type.
> PDO::PARAM_NULL (integer)
> Represents the SQL NULL data type.
> PDO::PARAM_INT (integer)
> Represents the SQL INTEGER data type.
> PDO::PARAM_STR (integer)
> Represents the SQL CHAR, VARCHAR, or other string data type.
> PDO::PARAM_LOB (integer)
> Represents the SQL large object data type.
> PDO::PARAM_STMT (integer)
> Represents a recordset type. Not currently supported by any drivers.
> PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT (integer)
> Specifies that the parameter is an INOUT parameter for a stored procedure. You must bitwise-OR this value with an explicit PDO::PARAM_* data type.
> ```

Comment: You can check (integer) value of constant by simply echo it: `echo PDO::PARAM_BOOL;` or `echo constant("PDO::PARAM_BOOL");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That output `(integer)` just means that the underlying constant uses an integer value to differentiate itself from the other constants in that group.

For example, on my installation some of those constants have the following (integer) values:

```
PDO::PARAM_NULL = 0
PDO::PARAM_INT = 1
PDO::PARAM_BOOL = 5
```

Similarly you'll see that `PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME` is listed as being of type `string`

Comment: now i understand it. thankss. i thought it is something i need to include in php script.

Answer (score 0):

The `(integer)` means the const value's data type, they are all integers.